Unable to find "Shared Drives" in Docker?
I had installed Docker Desktop v4.28.0 and Switch it to Windows Container. I want to share local drives but in the Docker Settings does not allow me:

As soon as i switch to Linux Container i can see the setting to mount the drives
I had successfully created an image of C compiler for Windows now i want to access the source files, which are present in on my local PC, to compile them with c compiler within the container
I already searrched alot on google but no helps so far

I had successfully created an image of C compiler for Windows now i want to access the source files, which are present in on my local PC, to compile them with c compiler within the container

Do not add details in comments. Instead, [edit] your question and add them there, where they can be seen. You can find the edit link in the lower left corner of your question, below the tags.

Windows containers do not run in a VM, there is nothing to share those drives with.

"I had successfully created an image of C compiler for Windows now i want to access the source files, which are present in on my local PC, to compile them with c compiler within the container" Typically you'd do this by using a COPY statement to copy source files into a container, then use RUN to run the compiler. See https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/
